# Clear Cache on browser close event in java script?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache

I set auto complete property. Now, when anyone close browser, i want to clear cache.

Because of auto complete property, it records earlier data. I want to clear data. It should record data for that session only.

I know, its not good practice. but, i am just asking for knowledge.

would be grateful for help...

Comment: autocomplete property? of what? do you mean the autocomplete setting of the browser?

Comment: Joseph- I set auto complete="on" to perticuler input field...So it can record data for that session..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set the `autocomplete="off"` property and then use cookies to store the values the user has typed in during that session.

If you do not supply an expiration date/time for the cookie, it "should" delete it self after the browser closes.

After that, you just need to implement an javascript based autocomplete dropdown when the user types in the values.

Comment: @Gavin- So you mean, whenever new user visit, I have to set auto complete to "on"??

and while existing i have to set it to "off"

but,How can i clear cache??

Comment: No, what I mean is you completely disable the browser's implementation of the autocomplete functionality by setting `autocomplete="off"` on all forms and input fields. You would then have to implement your own by means of collecting the values and storing them in cookies and then creating an javascript based autocomplete that would display the values from the cookies.

Comment: cont. From what I understand, you cannot clear the browser cache by javascript and even if you could, it would not solve your solution because you would have to use the unload or the beforeunload event to clear it, but this fires even if you move to another page within your site.